# Storing parameters from a graph and applying to other graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I would like to store the `xmin` and `xmax` parameters from one geom_histogram and apply them to a second geom_histogram.

I am putting both graphs on the same page using grid.arrange and would like them to have the same x range, while allowing the first graph to establish the range based on its data.  The second graph is produced from a subset of the first graphs data, so it will not have data that falls outside of the x-range established by the first.  But I don't want the range to shrink to fit the second graph. Using the example below I want the second graph to have the same x dimensions as the first graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gdata)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

a<-(ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy)) + geom_histogram() + labs(title = "All Cars"))
b<-(ggplot(subset(mpg, cyl == 4), aes(x = hwy)) + geom_histogram() + labs(title = "Just        4 Cylindars"))

grid.arrange(a,b, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Why don't you use facetting (with `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`)? That would create fixed scales automatically.

Comment: Can you facet when the data from one graph is a subset of the data used in the other graph?  I don't think that will work when the sets share records.  But I could be wrong...

Comment: You can duplicate the data in your data.frame: `DF2 <- DT[condition,]; DF$f <- "a"; DF2$f <- "b"; DF <- rbind(DF, DF2)` and then use `f` for facetting.

Comment: This worked...thanks Roland.  I selected the second answer b/c it was more precisely what I was looking for.  But your answer is a great workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faceting would clearly be cleaner. This is just a hack to show you how to look inside a ggplot-object.

Try adding this to the `b` plot commands:

```
... +xlim( range( a$data[ , a$labels$x] )*c(0.9,1.1) )
```

Needed to make limits expand in "both directions". If those limits had spanned neative an postive values a different strategy would have been needed. For interest you might want to look at:

```
 names(a)
 str(a)
range( a$data[ , a$labels$x] )
#[1] 12 44
```

Notice that there were no xlimits set in the `coordinates`-element and that we needed to use the original data that was stored along with the plot.

Comment: maybe a bit more robust: `ga = ggplot_build(a) ; range(ga[['data']][[1]][, "xmin"])`

Comment: There seem to be four auxiliary columns in the `ga$data[[1]]` object, two for the x-values and 2 for the y-values. Also quite a bit of accessory baggage.